# Speed up rendering of ContourPlot3D object

Tags: plotting, matrix, performance-tuning

Please can you advise me how to speed up the rendering of the following two planes? When I click and drag to rotate the plot, its movement is quite jerky. Presumably it is working harder than I need it to. The matrix equation `A.X = B` represents two flat planes embedded in 3D space. The solution of the system is the line of intersection of the two planes. I believe `ContourPlot3D` interprets the matrix equation as a list of the two planes. In fact, `A.X == B` evaluates as `{{x + y + z}, {x - y + 2 z}} == {{4}, {0}}`.

```
A = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 2}};
B = {{4}, {0}};
X = {{x}, {y}, {z}};
ContourPlot3D[A.X == B, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.6]], MeshStyle -> Gray]
```

I have tried using `Evaluate` on the expression `A.X == B`, and on the expression `A.X`, but to no avail.

You might think it better to separate the two planes, and use `Plot3D` command for each, but I would like my code to work automatically for general linear systems, i.e., for different choices of `A`, `B` and `X`, and I would like it to accomodate vertical planes, to which I guess `Plot3D` would not apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get rid of some extraneous `List` wrappers

```
A = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 2}};
B = {4, 0};
X = {x, y, z};
```

and then thread the two sides of your matrix equation over `Equals`.

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate @ Thread[A.X == B], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.6], MeshStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: plot]

The graphics shown above rotate in a nice, smooth fashion.

Comment: Thank you very much, @m_goldberg ! That is great. I know Mathematica's `Dot` command cleverly interprets vectors as row or column vectors depending on the context. I had hoped to insist that my column vectors be represented as nx1 matrices but I guess it is not important. I tried forcing this using `Evaluate[Thread[Map[Flatten, Map[Transpose, A.X == B]]]]` for the function in the first argument of ContourPlot3D but ContourPlot3D still didn't want to play ball. Do you have any idea why ?